# Has code formatting been "enhanced" after a recent update to this site's appearance?

Tags: support

I'm seeing code text with a variety of colors. Two recent examples:

- [installing kubuntu-desktop failed during 18.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104203/installing-kubuntu-desktop-failed-during-18-04-upgrade)
- [Bash file automation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104209/bash-file-automation)

In this image taken from the first one, there's text in light blue, dark blue, and red.

[image: code text colors]

And poking about, the light blue has "span class" `typ`, the dark blue is `kwd` and the dark red is `lit`. Other text is `pln`.

Is this a Winter Bash thing or is it the way code text will appear for the foreseeable future?

Comment: I believe they started detecting languages to avoid `<!-- language:  -->`.

Comment: I looked at U&L a bit but didn't come across anything similar.

Comment: @DKBose that’s just because they are too lazy to format their posts properly ]:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing there is [syntax highlighting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). This can be formatted explicitly in a post, for example, you can turn on Bash syntax highlighting for a code snippet by adding a tag before it:

```
<!-- language: lang-bash -->
```

Syntax highlighting is also [applied automatically according to a post's tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting). In this case, the question has the tag [python3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/python3), so all code in the question and all of its answers will be displayed with Python 3 syntax highlighting.

This is often not what you want... for example the question relates to Python but is mainly about package management and contains a code-formatted block of APT output. You can turn off syntax highlighting with a tag like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
```

or to turn off all syntax highlighting in a post

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
```

For more information see [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work? | MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Has it always been there and I just didn't notice? Or is this part of the new responsive design theme?

Comment: I'm itching to remove the python3 tag for that question.

Comment: @DKBose it's been there for as long as I've been using the site... I am now afk but I will find something on MSE later! Feel free to re-tag as appropriate